# RShiny: Refer to data from UI in server

Tags: r, shiny

Example Case: I have a function in my global.R called get_data which returns a list of many items. The reason I don't just put the data in global is so the data can automatically refresh after a certain amount of time

ui.R

```
my_data <- uiOutput("data") # Doesn't work
### Some more generic manipulation before final use

# The output of my_data will look like the following below.
my_data <- list()
my_data$first_entry <- c("a", "b", "d")
my_data$second_entry <- c("x", "y", "z") # and so on

shinyUI(navbarPage(theme=shinytheme("flatly"), 
  'App Name',
 tabPanel('Title',
           # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               width=3,
            

              
              # new box
              checkboxGroupButtons(
                'name',
                'label:',
                choices = sort(my_data$first_value),
                status = 'primary',
            
                 selected = sort(my_data$first_value)[1],
                size = 'xs'
                # inline = TRUE
              ))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(100000,session)
    
    get_data()
  })

  output$data <- renderUI({
    data()
    })
})
```

Two questions:

1. Is there any way of referencing my_data correctly?
2. If my function get_data is simply reading a (large) csv which is updated systematically. Is there a better way of doing it than I am currently doing it?

Comment: Two things: (1) `uiOutput` needs to go *within* `shinyUI(...)`, not outside of it. (2) `renderUI` needs to return a UI element, e.g., `selectInput` or similar. What are you intending `output$data` to look like?

Comment: Thanks for the response. First comment: Noted but quite difficult in my case. Can you put normal code into the ShinyUI which isn't some sort of output?

Secondsly: The output$data is going to be a list of vectors. Will edit question with more detail

Comment: Yes, so what type of HTML element is going to show a list of vectors? [`textAreaInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textAreaInput.html) comes to mind for viewing raw values.

Comment: @r2evans I have changed the question to include a better example of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're wondering how to define possible `choices=` for something within the UI element, when the data is both (1) undefined at the start, and (2) changing periodically. The answer to that is to define it "empty" and update it as the new data is found.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

get_data <- function() as.list(mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), size=3), sample(ncol(mtcars), size=3)])
logg <- function(...) message(paste0("[", format(Sys.time()), "] ", ...))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = "Hello",
    checkboxGroupButtons(inputId = "cb", label = "label:", choices = c("unk"), selected = NULL,
                         status = "primary", size = "xs"),
    br(),
    textOutput("txt"),
    br(),
    textAreaInput("txtarea", NULL, rows = 4)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({
      logg("in 'data'")
      invalidateLater(3000, session)
      get_data()
    })
    observe({
      logg("in 'observe'")
      req(length(data()) > 0)
      updateCheckboxGroupButtons(session = session, inputId = "cb", choices = names(data()))
      updateTextAreaInput(session, "txtarea", value = paste(capture.output(str(data())), collapse = "\n"))
    })
    output$txt <- renderPrint({
      logg("in 'txt'")
      req(length(data()) > 0)
      str(data())
    })
  }
)
```

Notice that the definition of `checkboxGroupButtons` starts with no real choices. I'd prefer to start it empty, but unlike `selectInput` and similar functions, it does not like starting with an empty vector. It is quickly (nearly-immediately) changed, so I do not see `"unk"` in the interface.

I demoed two options for "displaying" the data in its raw form: as an *output* `"txt"`, and as an updatable *input* `"txtarea"`. I like the latter because it deals well with fixed-width, but it requires an `update*` function (which is really not a big deal).

Comment: Sorry for the delay - took me a while to get this to work but this works perfectly. Thanks!